# How to prove the limits of a function when it goes to infinity is equal to 0?

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^a}{e^x} = 0$

> How do I prove this? I didn't get anywhere so I don't even think it is
> worth writing down how far I've. I've been stuck for a long time and
> would like help. And BTW no I've not learned l'hopital's rule yet
> (Someone suggested I solve it using it). Is there another way?

Comment: What tools do you have available? You can easily say that $e^x>1+x+x^2/2+...+x^{a+1}/(a+1)!$ if thats how you define $e^x$

Comment: @QC_QAOA But then what?

Comment: Step 1: Write the limit as $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x}{e^{x/a}}\right)^a$$. So it suffices to show $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{e^{x/a}}=0$$ Step 2: Compute the integral $$\int_0^{\infty}xe^{-x/a}\,dx$$ Step 3: Conclude

Answer (score 2):

We can prove this step by step, beginning with a sequences. Consider the sequence $\frac{n^a}{b^n}$, where $b>1$ and $a>0$ are real numbers. Let $b=1+\lambda$, where $\lambda>0$. Then by binom formula we have
$$b^n= (1+\lambda)^n=1+n\lambda+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\lambda^2+...>$$
$$>\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\lambda^2. $$
Because for $n>2$ we have $n-1>\frac{n}{2}$, we have
$$b^n>\frac{(b-1)^2}{4}n^2.$$
For $a=1$ we get that $\frac{n}{b^n}<\frac{4}{(b-1)^2}\cdot \frac{1}{n}$ and
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{b^n}=0.$$
Since this result is correct for all $b>1$, then taking $a>1$ we have
$$\frac{n^a}{b^n}=\left( \frac{n}{(b^{1/a})^n} \right)^a< \frac{n}{(b^{1/a})^n}.$$
Therefore,
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^a}{b^n}=0.$$
Proved thus for $a\ge 1$, this result is all the more true for $a<1$.

Now let's go to the limit of the function. From previous we already know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{b^n}=0$. Then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{b^n}=0$.

By the definition for given $\epsilon>0$ there exists natural number $N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $\frac{n+1}{b^n}<\epsilon$.

Now let $x>N+1$. If we put $n=[x]$, then
$$ n>N \text{ and } n\le x<n+1,$$
so
$$\frac{x}{b^x}<\frac{n+1}{b^n}<\epsilon$$
and $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\frac{x}{b^x}=0$.

Similarly, from here we get that for $a>1$
$$\frac{x^a}{b^x}=\left( \frac{x}{(b^{1/a})^x} \right)^a< \frac{x}{(b^{1/a})^x}.$$
Hence,
$$\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\frac{x^a}{b^x}=0.$$
Obviously it's true also for $a<1$.

For $b=e$ we get our result.